# Convert date string (from gmail) to timestamp | Python

Tags: python, datetime, gmail, utc, strptime

I want to save the received date of emails from a Gmail account into a time-series database.

The problem is that I cannot convert the string that I got from the email to timestamp.

I tried this:

```
from datetime import datetime

date1 = 'Thu, 28 May 2020 08:15:58 -0700 (PDT)' 

date1_obj = datetime.strptime(date1, '%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %z %Z')

print(date1_obj)
```

But got this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/format_date.py", line 11, in <module>
    date1_obj = datetime.strptime(date1, '%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %z %Z')
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.7/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/_strptime.py", line 577, in _strptime_datetime
    tt, fraction, gmtoff_fraction = _strptime(data_string, format)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.7/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/_strptime.py", line 359, in _strptime
    (data_string, format))
ValueError: time data 'Thu, 28 May 2020 08:15:58 -0700 (PDT)' does not match format '%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %z %Z'
```

Tried with or without parenthesis wrapping Timezone.
Read a lot, but nothing about how to deal with date strings containing "(PDT)" or any other timezones. It's very important to get the right date... If I run the same code without "(PDT)", got an incorrect time (because of my local time).

I know I can use string methods to manipulate it and convert to a right datetime, but I feel like this would be flexible.

Sorry for my terrible English.

Thank you!

Comment: Done. My appologies!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after all your answers, which were very helpful, I finally solved.

This is how:

```
>>> from email.utils import parsedate_tz, mktime_tz
>>> date = 'Thu, 28 May 2020 08:15:58 -0700 (PST)'
>>> timestamp = mktime_tz(parsedate_tz(date))
>>> timestamp
1590678958
>>>
```

I checked that timestamp, and stands to 12:15:58 local time, what it's exactly what I was looking for.

Thank you very much to everybody who took a minute to answer.

Comment: This also ignores the timezone's abbreviated name - since the UTC offset is unambiguous, that is fine. If you ever need to parse to the specific timezone: I've updated my answer how you could do that.

Answer (score 2):

you could use `dateutil`'s [parser](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/parser.html) to parse the string, automatically inferring the format:

```
import dateutil
s = 'Thu, 28 May 2020 08:15:58 -0700 (PDT)' 
dt = dateutil.parser.parse(s)
# datetime.datetime(2020, 5, 28, 8, 15, 58, tzinfo=tzoffset('PDT', -25200))
dt.utcoffset().total_seconds()
# -25200.0
```

Note that although the timezone is given a name ("PDT"), it is only a UTC offset of 25200 s. In many cases that is sufficient, at least to convert to UTC.

If you need the specific timezone (e.g. to account for DST transitions etc.), you can use a mapping dict that you supply to `dateutil.parser.parse` as `tzinfos`:

```
tzmap = {'PDT': dateutil.tz.gettz('US/Pacific'),
         'PST': dateutil.tz.gettz('US/Pacific')}

dt = dateutil.parser.parse(s, tzinfos=tzmap)
# datetime.datetime(2020, 5, 28, 8, 15, 58, tzinfo=tzfile('US/Pacific'))
dt.utcoffset().total_seconds()
# -25200.0
```

Comment: This actually helped. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Close, you forgot to put the bracket around the last entry.

```
date1_obj = datetime.strptime(date1, '%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %z (%Z)')
```

Comment: Yes, I tried with brackets too but still doesn't work :(

Thank you for your answer!

Comment: %Z cannot parse arbitrary timezone abbreviations, so unfortunately this (very likely) won't work for 'PDT'.

Answer (score -1):

If it does not work even if you enclose `%Z` in brackets then the problem lies within the %Z directive
https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html

> Support for the %Z directive is based on the values contained in
>   tzname and whether daylight is true. Because of this, it is
>   platform-specific except for recognizing UTC and GMT which are always
>   known (and are considered to be non-daylight savings timezones).

In example the following results in a `ValueError` for me (in Europe)

```
date1 = 'Thu, 28 May 2020 08:15:58 -0700 (PST)'
date1_obj = datetime.strptime(date1, '%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %z (%Z)')
print(date1_obj)
```

While with GMT it the output is `2020-05-28 08:15:58-07:00`

```
date1 = 'Thu, 28 May 2020 08:15:58 -0700 (GMT)'
date1_obj = datetime.strptime(date1, '%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %z (%Z)')
print(date1_obj)
```

Based on your comment under this answer you could split the string if the Timezone bit is not important:

```
date1 = 'Thu, 28 May 2020 08:15:58 -0700 (GMT)'
date1_obj = datetime.strptime(date1.split(" (")[0], '%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %z')
```

Comment: Got it. The %Z directive won't work for me (I'm from South America). Any idea on how to parse that date into datetime object without losing the right time?

For that "date1" string, I want to get 28/05/2020 12:15:58 (according to my timezone).

Thank you for your answer!

Comment: @AlejandroRojas you could do the following: 

date1 = 'Thu, 28 May 2020 08:15:58 -0700 (GMT)'
date1_obj = datetime.strptime(date1.split(" (")[0], '%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %z')

Comment: I got it, but this way I have 4 hours offset. The email was received 12:15:58 local time. This way, I have 8:15:58. I can do that, but I'm afraid that it would be a very specific workaround, and at the moment I have any change (like summer time), the script will store wrong date.

Comment: GMT does not have a UTC offset of -7 hours! I think replacing PST with GMT is misleading if you don't remove the -0700.